# Rails change_column migration using Postgresql function - time to integer (seconds since midnight)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-10

table `orders` has a `cuts_off_at` column that is of datatype `time without time zone`. This table and column have been in use for a while and, therefore, the table has many saved records. I realized I would like this column to instead be of datatype `integer` to represent `seconds since midnight`. How should I format the change_column line?

I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it right. I believe this has been my closest attempt:

`change_column :orders, :cuts_off_at, 'INTEGER USING EXTRACT(epoch from ('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::time - cuts_off_at))'`

which returns the error:

`syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end
...USING EXTRACT(epoch from ('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::time - cuts_...`

versions:

postgres version 10.12
rails 5.2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two migration approach isn't destructive and will let you use the postgres magic in a straight update statement. It will also let you make sure everything works as expected...

```
  def change
    rename_column :orders, :cuts_off_at, :cuts_off_at_old
    add_column :orders, :cuts_off_at, :integer
    execute("UPDATE orders SET cuts_off_at = EXTRACT(epoch from ('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::time - cuts_off_at_old))")
  end
```

Then you can simply drop the old column in a later migration...

```
 def change
    remove_column :orders, :cuts_off_at_old
 end
```

Or if you need an up down...

```
  def up
    rename_column :orders, :cuts_off_at, :cuts_off_at_old
    add_column :orders, :cuts_off_at, :integer
    execute("UPDATE orders SET cuts_off_at = EXTRACT(epoch from ('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::time - cuts_off_at_old))")
  end

  def down
    remove_column :orders, :cuts_off_at
    rename_column :orders, :cuts_off_at_old, :cuts_off_at
  end
```

Comment: while this seems to get me the correct values (using absolute value) I need a migration I can easily rollback. When I rollback this migration i get `This migration uses execute, which is not automatically reversible.` I would need to define a `def up` and `def down` sort of format

Comment: @alisontague Added the up/down -- the execute only filled the new column and can be forgotten.

Comment: amazing, thank you! i used `abs` by doing `execute("UPDATE orders SET cuts_off_at = ABS(EXTRACT(epoch from ('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::time - cuts_off_at_old)))")` to get the absolute value in case anyone runs into that issue